# Dynamically where clause causing problems with PDO prepared statement

Tags: php

I'm slowly transitioning my site to PDO prepared statements as it is much safer but recently I've run into a problem with this bit of code, it is a multi layered where query. The main issue is getting the values of  $offset and $total_records_per_page to work as it is loading the entire dataset,this code is for a pagination script that is working but it is not accepting the limit to load only a selected number of records and the rest is handled by the pagination code.

How can I properly add $offset and $total_records_per_page to work with this prepared statement?

```
// always initialize a variable before use!
$conditions = [];
$parameters = [];

// conditional statements
if (isset($_SESSION["SearchV"]) && $_SESSION["SearchV"]!="")
{
    // here we are using LIKE with wildcard search
    // use it ONLY if really need it
    $conditions[] = 'name LIKE ? LIMIT '.$offset.', '.$total_records_per_page.' ';
    $parameters[] = '%'.$_SESSION["SearchV"]."%";
}

if (isset($_SESSION["OrderValue"]) && $_SESSION["OrderValue"]!="")
{
    // here we are using equality
    $conditions[] = 'Genre LIKE ? LIMIT '.$offset.', '.$total_records_per_page.' ';
    $parameters[] = '%'.$_SESSION["OrderValue"]."%";
}


// the main query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM product";

// a smart code to add all conditions, if any
if ($conditions)
{
    $sql .= " WHERE ".implode(" AND ", $conditions);
}

// the usual prepare/execute/fetch routine
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($parameters);
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: NOTE: You can `LIMIT ?, ?`.

Comment: Add `LIMIT` here: `$sql .= " WHERE ".implode(" AND ", $conditions) . " LIMIT ?, ?";` Don't append it to the `$conditions` array.